# show $f< \infty a.e on [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let ${r_n}$ be all the rational numbers in $[0,1]$

Let $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}(0\le x\le1)
$

show $f< \infty a.e$ on $[0,1]$
Can anyone give me some hint?
Or what theorem should I use?

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem

Comment: @Danial Fischer Any more hint?

Comment: @梁楷葳 show that $f$ is integrable

Comment: @user251257 Why should we show that?

Comment: @梁楷葳 integrable functions are a.e. finite